# Unable to run a javascript program in Eclipse IDE for Web/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, newrelic

When i run my javascript program in Eclipse IDE, i get the error

[image: error]

How to configure Node.js in my system and is it even required to test a sample program for performance monitoring of a web link.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed NodeJS correctly and is it added to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Do i need to install this for even a test run, Since i have my work laptop and it needs admin rights for each installation.

Comment: Yes. You can't run NodeJS without NodeJS